# ColorHighlighter is not taking any effect on SBT3

Tags: colors, hex, sublimetext3, sublimetext, color-scheme

I go to :

[image]

and install :

[image]

with these settings :

[image]

and have no idea why hex is not my SBT3 still not display as its color form.

[image]

I've also tried : CSS

[image]

Reboot the IDE & even reboot the Mac OS X ... still not working.

Did I forgot to turn on some settings?

Can someone please help me ?

---

## Edit

**ColorHelper** works on the first try, right after install. Huge thanks to : *[@MattDMo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1426065/mattdmo)*

[image]

... but I am still curious if someone really knows what I did wrong.

Comment: I would recommend trying out [`ColorHelper`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/ColorHelper), which at least for me seems to Just Work™. Completely uninstall any other similar packages first, then try ColorHelper. There are some great docs [here](https://facelessuser.github.io/ColorHelper/).

Comment: It works on first try, thank-you!

Comment: Glad to hear it! I'll make it into a full answer if you want, so it doesn't get lost.

Comment: Ok. Please do. I’ll make sure to accept it

Answer (score 0):

Over the past few years I began having more and more problems with the different color highlighting packages available for Sublime, including Color Highlighter, which hasn't been updated in at least 3 years, and Color Highlight at 2½ years. Someone recommended [`ColorHelper`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/ColorHelper), and I've been happy with it ever since. Make sure you completely uninstall Color Highlighter and/or Color Highlight first, as I think I had issues with it before I did that. ColorHelper is in regular development with the release of the new v3, which apparently is a complete rewrite, and is easy to set up and use out of the box. There are a ton of customization options if you want to get into the weeds, and the author has been very responsive with some config issues I had recently. I would highly recommend it.

[image: Sublime color scheme example]